# How to embed video, image galleries, forms in Markdown files?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, markdown, r-markdown

I am going to make the React Toast UI editor (which is a markdown editor) customized to have videos(like youtube), image galleries (like Carousels), and forms (like contact form) which is supposed to send data to the backend to be saved onto DB.

Also, the saved MD data have to be able to rendered on React Native apps, that is why I am told to use Markdown Editor, because React Native apps can render MDs, not HTMLs.

I made a long research journey for that. Some say it is impossible, some say it is possible like Github markdown editor which allows embedding videos. I am still not sure if it is possible technically.

If possible, how to implement that?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you want. But I think you can look into MDX: https://mdxjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can save your videos, images etc in an `assets` file in your project and then access it with the following code:

e.g.

```
<img src="./assets/videos/videoName.png"
     alt="videoName"
     style="float: left; margin-right: 10px; width:50px; height:150px" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In my markdown editor:

```
<video src="https://www.zdslogic.com/data/files/uploads/richard.campion/zdslogic-video-one.mp4" controls="controls" style="max-width: 500px;"></video>
```

Works in my Angular project using marked